# LM75sensor not showing output

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am trying to get temperature measurements from Lm75 sensor with Arduino Uno. The code gets compiled and uploaded successfully but on the serial monitor it is not showing any results.
I am using the code and Library from this tutorial.

https://electropeak.com/learn/interfacing-lm75-temperature-sensor-with-arduino/

```
#include <Temperature_LM75_Derived.h>


Generic_LM75 LM75;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.print(LM75.readTemperatureC());
  Serial.println(" C");

  delay(1000 );
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.